# Android: Spinner in fragments

Tags: android-layout, spinner

I don't know what is happening here, I am new to Android. Actually when I click on the spinner it doesn't show anything, the first value is selected by default and when I click the spinner nothing happens. I have tried it different devices and avd too still I don't know what to do. I have tried another method too (Implementing OnItemSelectedListener) but still same result. There is no error but the code doesn't seem to work and I have debugged the application too and the adapter has the 7 items but still no use.

Result Image:
When I opened the fragment the spinner with selected value and Toast:

[image]

```
import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;

public class Attendance_fragment extends android.app.Fragment  {


public Attendance_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendance_layout, container, false);
    Spinner spinner;
    spinner =(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerattendancedates);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.attendance_dates, simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

fragment_attendance_layout.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerattendancedates"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="440dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period2"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period3"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period4"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period5"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period6"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period7"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/period8"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/absentorpresent"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My strings.XML

```
<string-array name="attendance_dates">
    <item>Date 1</item>
    <item>Date 2</item>
    <item>Date 3</item>
    <item>Date 4</item>
    <item>Date 5</item>
    <item>Date 6</item>
    <item>Date 7</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally corrected it. My problem was i have an "android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView" in Navigation Drawer Activity from where i open this Fragment. When I removed this. It worked. This is also similar for buttons which is not clickable at some circumstances.